# G++ complains "undefined reference to" while GCC succeeds

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have a program which calls some library function. I can compile with GCC sucessfully. However, when I switched to G++ 4.7 (since I need to add C++ code in it), I got

```
undefined reference to <a function name here>
```

The compile command is like:

`<gcc or g++> foo.c -o foo <path-to-a-static-library>.a -l<the library>`

The library containing functions I called is written by C.

**How can I fix it?** Recompile the library with G++? This is bad, since we have other C programs using that library.

Comment: Name mangling!!! Lookup `extern "C"` ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thx. I googled a result like "the C code header should be included in extern if need to used in C++". So, if the library does not have that extern C, I can do nothing?

Comment: @PengZhang do `extern "C" {
#include "library.h"
}` from your C++ code

Comment: I'd recommend putting the `extern "C" { ... }` into the library headers, appropriately guarded by `#ifdef __cplusplus` to have it work with both C and C++: it is crucial to allow migration to C++.

Comment: @AntonSavin Thx. It works now. I should contact the library author to add extern "C" guard into their library headers.

Comment: `extern "C" { #include "library.h" }` is not a good idea as `library.h` may include standard headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the headers for the C library you should guard them with an appropriate `extern "C"` section:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* C declarations for the library */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If you absolutely cannot change the header files, you should make sure that you can change the header files. If this still absolutely isn't an option, try harder. Only after hitting brick walls of resistance put an `extern "C"` declaration around the `#include` directive:

```
extern "C" {
#include "c-library-header.h"
}
```

The reason of the approach putting `extern "C"` around the `#include`-directive is that it inhibits future migration of the header file to include C++ features: since the external include guards will be littered around the the code base, it becomes a maintenance nightmare to fix them when C++ features show up in `"c-library-header.h"`. This may not be considered a big problem with the current software but any successful software tends to grow and migrations like removal of `extern "C"` declarations become problematic.